# When trying to add a Grafana widget to the Homer-App I get the error: refused to connect

Tags: grafana

I am using Homer-App 7 and Grafana. I am trying to create a Grafana Metrics Widget panel on the Homer GUI, the problem is that when I try to create the widget, I get the error => refused to connect, however, when I enter the url for Grafana I see all the widgets I created on Grafana, so this tells me that it can open the Grafana url I am pointing to.  I am not sure why it can see my Grafana widgets from Homer, but yet I get this error.  Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, if you looked on the Chrome console debug log, you could see that the Grafana frames would not load because X-Frame was set to "deny".  If you install "Ignore X-Frame header" from the chrome web store, you can then load Grafana widgets with Homer-App.

I only tried with Chrome and did not test with any other browsers.